# Why I can't create a new table using simply query CREATE TABLE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, create-table

MS SQL SERVER
When I do query

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.transactions
```

it list all rows and colums perfectly.

Problem is when I'm trying to do a new table with CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.all_transactions 
SELECT *
FROM dbo.transactions
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.all_transactions AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.transactions
```

Always I get strange error

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'
```

There is only * next to SELECT. How it could be an "Incorrect syntax"?

I tried changing the table name or using another table, but it doesn't work.
I checked the names of the columns are unique. They are unique.

Comment: Create table requires the column information syntax ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 for your reading pleasure.

Comment: I wonder if maybe you want a `View` for this.

Comment: You have to follow the correct syntax.  You can't just write whatever, and expect SQL Server to somehow understand what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to create table `all_transactions` copying the data from `transactions`
Try out this:

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.all_transactions
FROM dbo.transactions;
```